# Is it safe to always reallocate memory before freeing it - C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

Assume code like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int value = 42;
    void* pointer = (void*) &value;

    // Free stack memory
    free(pointer);

    return 0;
}
```

This code results in *undefined behavior* because it tries to de-allocate memory on the stack.

---

But I was wondering; What about re-allocating a pointer everytime before we free it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int value = 42;
    void* pointer = (void*) &value;

    // Allocate pointer on heap, then free memory
    pointer = realloc(pointer, sizeof pointer);
    free(pointer);

    return 0;
}
```

My assumption being that this sends the pointer to heap memory so it can be freed appropriately.

All of this is with the context that the programmer does not know on what memory (heap or stack) the pointer is specified on (At which point, the design of the program comes into question, but I wouldn't digress).

---

#### Query

Is this a safe-way to ensure memory gets freed properly **or** is it improper and create garbage objects left in memory?

Comment: That `std::free(pointer);` is not C code. Please check your tags or change the shown code.

Comment: In C you can only `realloc()` a pointer obtained from `malloc()` (or `calloc()`) ... or another `realloc()` which used a pointer from `malloc()` ... and the same for `free()`.

Comment: This is not C, but C++

Comment: In addition to the other issues of not realloc'ing stack memory, this is not the safe way to call realloc.  You need to save the realloc'ed memory in a temp variable and check it for NULL before proceeding.

Comment: Whether or not you want to free something depends on whether or not you are its sole owner. If you don't know that, no method of attempting to free it is safe.

Comment: Can you call `delete` on stack memory? `reallc` is an abbreviation of `reallocate` which means "allocating a new" which means a previously allocated dynamic memory happened before reallocating.

Comment: How to ensure memory is freed correctly in order of preference:  1. Use Automatic allocations. 2. [Use containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). 3. [Use smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). 4. Use `new`/`delete`. 5. Use `malloc` and friends with `free`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't `realloc` stack memory - so you still have undefined behavior.

The realloc(3) man page will tell you this:

> Reallocates the given area of memory. It must be previously allocated
>   by malloc(), calloc() or realloc() and not yet freed with a call to
>   free or realloc. Otherwise, the results are undefined.